Use General Properties of Bessel Functions to Solve Bessel Equation
The Bessel Functions $C_\nu (z) = J_\nu(z), Y_\nu(z), H_\nu ^{(1)}(z), H_\nu ^{(2)}(z)$ fulfil the properties (see e.g. A. Apelblat, "Bessel and Related Functions - Volume 1 Theoretical Aspects", 2020, page 13)

$\frac{2 \nu}{z} C_\nu (z) = C_{\nu -1} (z) + C_{\nu +1} (z)$,
$\frac{d}{dz} C_\nu (z) = \frac{C_{\nu -1} (z) - C_{\nu +1} (z)}{2}$.

Shouldn't it then be possible to fulfill the Bessel equation with these properties?
Every time I use these properties and apply them to the Bessel equation, I end up with $\frac{z}{2}(C_{\nu -1} (z) - C_{\nu +1} (z)) = 0$.
Where is my mistake?
